# How to detect mobile(not tablet) requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0

How can I detect mobile devices(but not tablets) requests in `ASP.NET` `MVC` application?

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET, you can easily detect the mobile device request using Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice property and Request.UserAgent.

The following code checks the IsMobileDevice property and redirects to the mobile specific page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
    {
        Response.Redirec("~/default_mobile.aspx");          
    }
}
```

If you request "default.aspx" from mobile browser, it will redirect to default_mobile.aspx page

[Read here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213825/ASP-net-Mobile-device-detection) where they explain in detail

Some times this may not work for some tablets

For that you have to use Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth and validate against values of various screen sizes to achieve this . I think that will be the only way left to do it in the server side

If you want to trust client side javascript . There are varous scripts available  to do that .

Check this [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) which may also help you .

Comment: The OP is using ASP.NET MVC I think.

Comment: As far as i know IsMobileDevice = true if request is came from phone or tablet. But i need to handle only phone requests.

Comment: Works in MVC To: HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts Ok I was referring to Page_Load.

Comment: Yeah @k0lpak I got to know that thats y I reedited my post check it out again

Comment: I used this, but doesn't detect my android tablet.

Comment: @marko I am sorry, It did work for me I am not sure which android tablet you are using can you share the code you are using ,

Answer (score 0):

As the other bloke said, you can use `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice`

Either in your controller or in your layout page

**Razor**. You can do this in the layout page and it'll change depending on device e.g.

```
@if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice) {

}
```

**Controller** for an individual View e.g.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
         return View("Index.Mobile");
    else
         return View();      
}
```

An alternative is to use this API called 51Degrees.mobi. I personally haven't used it, but it looks pretty good and very complete: http://51degrees.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVC

Also, this has some more information on the subject of mobile detection. http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application

Comment: I want to use free tool, but 51degrees in their lite version supports only IsMobile property, but not IsTablet.